# How many ways are there to wear $5$ different rings in $4$ different fingers and also the order in which the ring is placed in a finger matters?

Tags: combinatorics

so, we know how to solve if the question was only $5$ different rings in $4$ different fingers, which is $4^5$. but what if internal order of rings within the finger matters, is this counted in this answer or we have a different answer?

Answer (score 3):

There are $5!=120$ ways to arrange the rings in order.  Divide them into $4$ groups and place the first group, in order, on the first finger, the second group on the second finger, and so on.

We have five rings to place on $4$ fingers.
By stars and bars, there are $\binom83=56$ ways to do this, so in all we have $$120\cdot 56 = 6720$$ ways.

Comment: @user2661923 Yes, you're right.  I must be getting very sleepy.  Thank you.  I'll fix it.

Comment: +1.00 for elegance, and -0.49 for making my kludgy approach pale.  I rounded up.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this is simply a take off my shoes and count problem.

Type of distribution : 
Explanation 
Number of ways

$5,0,0,0 :$
$4$ ways of choosing which finger, $5!$ ways of permuting the rings. 
$T_1 = 4 \times 5!.$

$4,1,0,0 :$
$4$ ways of choosing the heavy finger, $3$ ways of choosing the 2nd finger, $5$ ways of choosing which ring goes on the 2nd finger, $4!$ ways of permuting the rings on the heavy finger. 
$T_2 = 4 \times 3 \times 5 \times 4!.$

$3,2,0,0 :$
$4$ ways of choosing the heavy finger, 3 ways of choosing the 2nd finger, $\binom{5}{3}$ ways of selecting which rings go on the heavy finger, $3!$ ways of permuting the rings on the heavy finger, $2!$ ways of permuting the rings on the 2nd finger. 
$T_3 = 4 \times 3 \times \binom{5}{3} \times 3! \times 2!.$

$3,1,1,0 :$
$4$ ways of choosing the heavy finger, $3$ ways of choosing the no-ring-finger, $\binom{5}{3}$ ways of selecting the rings on the heavy finger, $2$ ways of selecting the ring on the 1st light finger, $3!$ ways of permuting the rings on the heavy finger. 
$T_4 = 4 \times 3 \times \binom{5}{3} \times 2 \times 3!.$

$2,2,1,0 :$
$4$ ways of choosing the no-ring-finger, $3$ ways of choosing the 1-ring finger, $5$ ways of selecting the ring for the 1-ring finger, $\binom{4}{2}$ ways of distributing the rings on the 2-ring fingers, $(2! \times 2!)$ ways of permuting the rings on the 2-ring fingers. 
$T_5 = 4 \times 3 \times 5 \times \binom{4}{2} \times 2! \times 2!.$

$2,1,1,1 :$
$4$ ways of choosing the 2-rings-finger, $\binom{5}{2}$ ways of selecting which rings go on the 2-rings finger, $2!$ ways of permuting these 2 rings, $3!$ ways of distributing the remaining rings among the 3 light fingers.
$T_6 = 4 \times \binom{5}{2} \times 2! \times 3!.$

Final answer:
$$T_1 + T_2 + T_3 + T_4 + T_5 + T_6.$$

**Edit**
I got a total of $6720$ ways.